# What is the poem featured in the album cover for The Black Saint and the Sinner Lady?

Tags: jazz, album

The excerpt from the album cover reads “Touch my beloved’s thought while her world’s affluence crumbles at my feet.”

I found some other websites with the same questions, but none really had satisfactory answers:

https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20101019151111AAS2IDU
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk:The_Black_Saint_and_the_Sinner_Lady
https://www.reddit.com/r/Jazz/comments/i97t11/the_black_saint_and_the_sinner_lady_poem/

Most speculate it's his poem, but I was wondering if someone could confirm. The resources they mentioned to look for include the liner notes and the biography *Beneath the Underdog*, but I can't say that I'm passionate enough to keep searching past this point, so I'm hoping someone else could help with my curiosity. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Mingus wrote poetry, he even recited it over some of his works, for example on "Let My Children Hear Music", so we can safely assume the excerpt is by him even though I can't provide a reference.